# Weird behaviour of SUM and CONCAT in MySql

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

If I want to make a sum of a specific numeric column in MySQL, I do

```
SELECT SUM(MyColumn) FROM MyTable WHERE 1;
```

This returns for example number 100.

But I'd like to prepend some text to the sum value, so I do

```
SELECT CONCAT('Sum is: ',SUM(MyColumn)) FROM MyTable WHERE 1;
```

but instead of getting `Sum is: 100` I get something like `546573743a20343030`.

Is this a bug or a feature? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT CONCAT('Sum is: ',CAST(SUM(MyColumn) AS varchar(20))) FROM MyTable WHERE 1;
```

Casting to varchar doesn't work: getting SQL syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a feature. Try casting once in a while. `CONCAT('Sum is: ', CAST(SUM(MyColumn) AS varchar(20))`

Comment: 1) why the downvote? This is a well posed question. 2) I tried casting, doesn't work.

Comment: What's the datatype of `MyColumn`?, what value does `SUM(MyColumn)` returns?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a2f/1  What is the type of `MyColumn`?  Can you possibly use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create an example of this issue?

Comment: The downvote is for not being helpful to future visitors. You need to `CAST` the `SUM()`. Works fine [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2786/4).

Comment: It's an integer. And when I sum it it's of course also an integer.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Works fine without the `CAST`, too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a2f/1

Comment: @RocketHazmat Lots of things work the way they shouldn't in MySQL. It doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Nope, SELECT CONCAT('Test: ',CAST(SUM(Counter) AS varchar(20))) FROM `Table` WHERE 1 doesn't work for me. Then I think this might be a problem with my server.

Comment: @NumberFour Use `char`

Comment: what is the actual result of `SUM(Counter)`?

Comment: Aaah, get it. Char works!

Comment: @NumberFour Apparently MySQL doesn't accept `varchar` as a cast type. Another awesome "feature"

Comment: I thought CAST wouldn't help when varchar didn't work. It's weird though that char works.

Comment: I see I didn't know that. Luckily we'll be migrating to Postgres soon. Anyway, thanks, you can put it as an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: Apparently this behavior also happens on SQL Server. I learned something new; have an upvote.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Well, define which behavior. The output `546573743a20343030` is absolutely non-sensical.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The implicit conversion between a string and non-string. The hex output is beyond me

Comment: Yeah, it always gave some hexadecimal string like this.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Well, I know that - just wanted you to clarify your comment, so readers don't jump to the conclusion that SQL Server is so fundamentally broken like this. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah we don't want that.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I updated the question, you can post your answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [FreshPrinceOfSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679449/freshprinceofso) suggested in the comments below my question, MySQL server doesn't handle casts to `varchar`.

So even though the query

```
SELECT CONCAT('Sum is: ',CAST(SUM(MyColumn) AS varchar(20))) FROM MyTable WHERE 1;
```

results in syntax error, casting to `char` instead works just fine:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Sum is: ',CAST(SUM(MyColumn) AS char(20))) FROM MyTable WHERE 1;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much.