# MYSQL: SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(`sale_price`)) gives a random value

Tags: mysql, currency, money-format

In MYSQL:

The SELECT statement ...

```
SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(`sale_price`) ) FROM `temp_table`
```

... gives a random output value, while ...

```
SELECT concat('$ ', FORMAT(SUM(`sale_price`), 2)) FROM `temp_table`
```

... gives the correct output.

Why does this happen? What's wrong with the first statement?

Here's the SQL Code of the table on which I tried these statements.

SQL Code:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 01, 2016 at 11:04 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.21
-- PHP Version: 5.6.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `book_shop`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `temp_table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_table` (
`sale_price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `temp_table`
--

INSERT INTO `temp_table` (`sale_price`) VALUES
('21.20'),
('46.80'),
('23.50'),
('54.70');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Some data from the `transactions` table would be nice here.

Comment: Pretty strange, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GNPffqwSEPAitK6okAy71/0 seems to back your claim: the result of that `CONCAT` call is some kind of buffer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22023468 shows similar behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(`sale_price`) ) FROM `transactions`
```

... and ...

```
SELECT concat('$ ', FORMAT(SUM(sale_price), 2)) FROM `transactions`
```

... do the exact same thing, only `FORMAT(... , 2)` ensures that your sales price is formatted as a decimal with two digits behind the `.` (which is the format typically used for monetary values in transactions between humans).

Without the `FORMAT(... , 2)`, the format of your sales price depends on the format of your sales price in the database.

---

#### Note 1

When I try ...

```
SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(sale_price)) FROM test
```

... on a test table that contains the values `21.20`, `46.80`, `23.50` & `54.70` in the column `sale_price`, I get the following output :

- `$ 146.20000076293945` if I use `FLOAT`
- `$ 146.20` if I use something like `DECIMAL(10,2)`

These are the expected results in both cases. As you can see, `FLOAT` is less precise and should be avoided for that reason.

---

#### Note 2

Based on the information provided in the comments below, it appears that there's something wrong with your installation of PHPMyAdmin. Please uninstall and reinstall it (preferably a different version).

Comment: Only the second statement is giving the right output which is in my case: $ 34,577.80

For the first statement the output is a huge number in the power of e but not '$ 34,577.80'!

Comment: @shiv : What's the exact output you get for your first statement? Also, do you know the individual sales prices in your database that are used for that sum? You need to give us more information if you want us to be more specific!

Comment: Ok. Let's simplify this since the transactions table has more than 8000 rows.

I have created a table named `temp_table`. It has a column named `sale_price`. The table has four rows and the `sale_price` values are 21.20, 46.80, 23.50 & 54.70.

Statement 1: SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(`sale_price`)) FROM `temp_table`
Output: 24203134362e3230

Statement 2: SELECT concat('$ ', FORMAT(SUM(`sale_price`),2)) FROM `temp_table`
Output: $ 146.20

Comment: @shiv : What datatype are you using for your `sales_price` column? When I try `SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(sale_price)) FROM test` on a test table that contains the values `21.20`, `46.80`, `23.50` & `54.70` in the column `sale_price`, I get (1) `$ 146.20000076293945` if I use `FLOAT` and (2) `$ 146.20` if I use `DECIMAL(10,2)`... which are the expected results in both cases! — **Note :** you should always use decimals to store monetary values

Comment: The datatype of `sale_price` is decimal(8,2).

Comment: @shiv : I can not reproduce your error. If I use a datatype `DECIMAL(X,2)` (where X is say 5 or higher), I get `$ 146.20` whenever I run `SELECT concat('$ ', SUM(sale_price)) FROM test`

Comment: @shiv : Please export your `temp_table` and copy-paste the output of your export file in an edit to your question.

Comment: @ John: I have edited the question with the SQL Code for creating `temp_table`.

Comment: @shiv : I just imported your table into my system. Using the EXACT same query and the EXACT same database structure you're using, I still get `$ 146.20` as output ([see screenshot](http://imgur.com/QAkWSBo)). So neither your DB structure nor your query appear to be the problem... which makes no sense to me... at all! Now I'm starting to think you just might be pulling an April Fool's joke on me :-p

Comment: No no. I am serious. I tried the exact same query as yours on `temp_table` and I got 24203134362e3230 as output ( See Screenshot: http://imgur.com/WX2CDbd ). The output is on PHPMyAdmin. So, what do you think is the reason?

Comment: @shiv : To be honest, I'm kinda clueless. With (1) the exact same table structure, (2) the exact same data and (3) the exact same query, output should always be identical. With those three parameters being identical, I can't think of any reason why you'd be getting that strange output while I'm getting the expected output of `$ 146.20`.

Comment: Hey, here's the thing. When I connect to MySQL server from PHP and retrieve the result I am getting the correct output which is `$ 146.20`. So, that means, the query isn't just working on my PHPMyAdmin. Can this be the case?

Comment: @shiv : It is definitely possible that your PHPMyAdmin is corrupted in some way. In fact, that's about the only explanation that makes sense, given you do get the correct output when executing the query yourself from PHP. I suggest you uninstall + re-install (a different version of) PHPMyAdmin and try again.

Comment: @ John: Hey, I upgraded my PHPMyAdmin to the latest version and ran the query. This time I got the correct output for the same query (See screenshot: http://imgur.com/CajOSCx). You were totally right when you said my PHPMyAdmin is corrupt in some way. Now, the problem is solved! Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: @shiv : You're welcome. For future reference (in case anyone else with the same problem stumbles upon your question), I added the solution to my answer as a second note.