# Unexpected values in MySQL SELECT CONCAT() column output

Tags: mysql, string, function, concatenation

I have a CONCAT function setup as follows (full SQL at the bottom):

`concat('Disadvantaged (', sum(1), ')') as 'Focus Group'`

I'm expecting the word Disadvantaged followed by a total in brackets as the query is grouped i.e. `Disadvantaged (39)`

However, instead I am getting: `446973616476616e74616765642028333929`

Here's my full query:

```
SELECT Subject,
    concat('Disadvantaged (', sum(1), ')') as 'Focus Group',
    Avg(G1.Pointscore) as 'Average Result',
    Avg(G2.Pointscore) as 'Average KS4 Target',
    Avg(G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore) as 'Average Residual',
    sum(1) as 'No. Students',
    /* Attainment totals */
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore >= 7 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. A*-A',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. A*-C',
    /* Attainment percentages */
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore >= 7 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as 'A*-A',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore >= 5 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as 'A*-C',
    /* Progress totals */
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. Sig Above',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. Above',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. On',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore = -1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. Below',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore < -1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'No. Sig Below',
    /* Progress percentages */
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore > 1 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as  'Sig Above',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore = 1 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as 'Above',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore = 0 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as 'On', 
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore = -1 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as 'Below',
    sum(case when G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore < -1 then 1 else 0 end) / sum(1) as 'Sig Below'
FROM Students S
INNER JOIN Results R ON S.UPN = R.UPN
INNER JOIN Grades G1 ON Result = G1.Grade
INNER JOIN Grades G2 ON Target = G2.Grade
WHERE Disadvantaged = 'Y'
GROUP BY Subject
```

UPDATE: I found another post that raises and answers this question here:

[Weird behaviour of SUM and CONCAT in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023468/weird-behaviour-of-sum-and-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @Vatev Check out this simple [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/77014).  You'll see the gibberish coming back when embedding `SUM` inside of `CONCAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can put the `SUM` function into the `CONCAT` function, and I also got gibberish when trying this locally.  One workaround would be to wrap your current query, and then use only *columns* inside `CONCAT`, e.g.

```
SELECT t.Subject,
       CONCAT('Disadvantaged (', t.`No. Students`, ')') AS 'Focus Group',
       t.`Average Result`,
       t.`Average KS4 Target`,
       t.`Average Residual`,
       t`.No. Students`,
       ...
FROM
(
    SELECT Subject,
           AVG(G1.Pointscore) AS 'Average Result',
           AVG(G2.Pointscore) AS 'Average KS4 Target',
           AVG(G1.Pointscore - G2.Pointscore) AS 'Average Residual',
           SUM(1) AS 'No. Students',
           ...
    FROM Students S
    ...
) t
```

**Update:**

I also tried switching to the pipe operator for concatenation via:

```
SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT'
```

followed by your concatenation with `SUM(1)` via

```
SELECT 'Disadvantaged (' || SUM(1) || ')'
```

but this also did not work.  Here is a Fiddle appearing to show that switching to the pipe operator also does not work:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: thanks for that. It works, the one drawback being is that that performance of my query has taken quite a hit. Up to 30 seconds for a query that previously took milliseconds.

Comment: @Matt Can you try doing `SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';` followed by `SELECT 'Disadvantaged (' || SUM(1) || ')' FROM Students s` ... what output do you get?